# I have a warning about a line of code that doesn't exist in my app

Tags: react-native, debugging

I am getting this error, its causing my iOS app to crash and my android app not to launch at all. However, this code does not exist anywhere in my code!

any clues would be much appreaciated

Here is the warning from console:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `fontSize` of type `string` supplied to `Text`, expected `number`.
Bad object: {
  "fontSize": "24",
  "fontFamily": "ionicons",
  "fontWeight": "normal",
  "fontStyle": "normal"
}
    in Text (at create-icon-set.js:81)
    in Icon (at createIconSet.js:41)
    in Icon (at Routes.js:314)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:240)
    in AnimatedComponent(View) (created by TabBarIcon)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (created by TabBarIcon)
    in TabBarIcon (created by TabBarBottom)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (created by TouchableWithoutFeedbackWrapper)
    in TouchableWithoutFeedback (created by TouchableWithoutFeedbackWrapper)
    in TouchableWithoutFeedbackWrapper (created by TabBarBottom)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (created by TabBarBottom)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in View (created by StackView)
    in StackView (created by StackView)
    in StackView
    in Unknown (created by Navigator)
    in Navigator (created by NavigationContainer)
    in NavigationContainer (at route.js:12)
    in Routers (at App.js:40)
    in PersistGate (at App.js:47)
    in Provider (at App.js:46)
    in App (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in DevAppContainer (at AppContainer.js:121)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer...
```

Comment: You have not used `"fontSize": "24",` in your code? Search it again. Try checking some dependencies that you have added before app crash.

Comment: no, not used it anywhere, I searched many times for it. and I dont remember how long this issue was there for, or the latest dependencies I installed before it happend.

Comment: @MoAlgh Check within the libraries' code.

Comment: the error says that happened on `create-icon-set.js:81` , read the first line of error message: `    in Text (at create-icon-set.js:81)
`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I been looking for this line:

```
"fontSize": "24",`
```

in my code its like this:

```
<Ionicons name="xxxxx" size="24" />
```

changed it to

```
<Ionicons name="xxxx" size={24} />
```